# assembly language: 8 bit versions of 64 bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

So, let's say I'm working with the registers `%rax` and `%rdi`.

As a basic example, let's say `%rax` is equivalent to `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` and `%rdi` is equivalent to `0xbbbbccccddddeeff`.

Something simple like `movq %rdi, %rax` is simple enough to me. We simply move the value in `%rdi` into `%rax`.

So, say we have the following:

```
movq %rdi, %rax
movb %dil, %al
```

The first instruction would have `%rax` equal `0xbbbbccccddddeeff`.

But I'm not sure how I would determine the value of `%rax` after the second instruction is implemented due to the fact that we are using the 8-bit versions of `%rdi` and `%rax`.

I'm very new to assembly language and there are quite a few things I'm pretty confused about. I've been doing a lot of research and studying up on it, but I'm still pretty lost, so I thought asking a clarifying question here would help me out. Any explanation on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second instruction `movb %dil, %al` only replaces the lowest 8-bits of `%rax`. The rest stays as it is.

So `%rax` would be `0xbbbbccccddddeeff`, because the lowest 8-bits would be copied two times.

Without the first instruction `movq %rdi, %rax` - which copies the whole register to `%rax` - only the lowest 8-bits would be replaced and the value of `%rax` would have been `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaff`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It was very helpful for you to explain it in the absence of the first instruction as well.

Comment: Although, how would this work if I wasn't using two 8-bit registers? For example, if I did ```movzbw %dil, %ax```. What's the correct thing to do for an 8-bit and 16-bit register instruction like htis?

Comment: It's nothing special. In the case of `movzbw %dil, %ax` the 8-bit value of `%dil` will be zero extended to the unsigned 16-bit value of `%ax` - and written to it (the lowest 16-bit of `%rax`). So the lowest 16 bits of `%rax` would be overwritten.

Comment: @larn: Watch out, however, that 32-bit instructions are different.  `movl %edi, %eax` will copy the low 32 bits and **zero** the upper 32 bits.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6

Comment: @zx485 I'm a little confused about the language of assembly at the moment, considering I'm such a newbie. What would the hex value be of %rax after performing such an instruction? I don't think I'm interpreting your words correctly at all. Having a value to look at will definitely help me put the pieces together

Comment: With your given two instructions, the value of `%rax` would be `0xbbbbccccdddd00ff` (zero extending 0xFF to 0x00FF).

Comment: @larn: You can and should single step code in a debugger and watch register values change.  If you're ever not sure about something, just try it yourself.  Just put these two instructions at the top of `_start:` or `main:` and assemble into an executable that you run GDB on.